# Convert hexadecimal byte array to int

Tags: java

I read 4 hexadecimal bytes from input stream into an array on server side from client, f.e. \x00\x00\x02\x24 which is 224 in hex. I need to convert it into an int. How could this be done?

Comment: I'm missing something. It sounds like your input is just `new byte[] { 0, 0, 2, 36 }`; but there's nothing "hexadecimal" about that (other than that you've chosen to write it as `\x00\x00\x02\x24` for some reason in the text of the question itself). Can you clarify?

Comment: I'm sorry that's as much as I know. I'm not sure how to check it, the program I'm writing does also other tasks with multiple threads at once.

Answer (score 1):

Shift and sum them (as it done in [`DataInputStream#readInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt--))

```
byte[] bytes = {0, 0, 0x2, 0x24};
int i = ((bytes[0] << 24) + (bytes[1]<< 16) + (bytes[2]<< 8) + (bytes[3] << 0));
System.out.println(i);
```

Output:

548

Maybe you're looking for [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html)?

```
byte[] bytes = {0, 0, 0x2, 0x24};
DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
System.out.println(inputStream.readInt());
```

Output:

548

Comment: I'm lookimg for something like this, only shouldn't 224 hex be 548 decimal?

Comment: @DavidBulko yes, 0x224 = 548